# How to run TypeScript code in Angular2 after all components have been rendered?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created 2 simple components in my angular2 app called IndexPageComponent and DetailPageComponent:

**IndexPageComponent**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'indexpage',
  template: `
      <div data-page="index" class="page">
      </div>
  `
})

export default class IndexPageComponent {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**DetailPageComponent**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'detailpage',
  template: `
      <div data-page="detail" class="page cached">
      </div>
  `
})

export default class DetailPageComponent {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Both components are used in this component:

**MainViewComponent**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import IndexPageComponent from './IndexPageComponent';
import DetailPageComponent from './DetailPageComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-view',
  template: `
    <div class="pages">
        <indexpage></indexpage>
        <detailpage></detailpage>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [IndexPageComponent, DetailPageComponent]
})

export default class MainViewComponent {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
  <body>
    <div class="views">
      <main-view class="view view-main"></main-view>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I also use another UI framework (called Framework7) which needs to be initialized **after** all components as well as the DOM is ready.

For initialization I need to run the following code:

```
var fw7App = new Framework7();
var fw7MainView = fw7App.addView('.view-main', {
    domCache: true //enable inline pages
});
```

Unfortunately, I need to wait with this until all components and DOM are ready. Where do I put this code in Angular2 + TypeScript project?

I tried to put it into an own .ts file and run it:

```
import 'framework7'
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import MainViewComponent from './MainViewComponent';

var fw7App = new Framework7();
var fw7MainView = fw7App.addView('.view-main', {
    domCache: true //enable inline pages
});

bootstrap(MainViewComponent);
```

But this doesn't work because it's called to early (Angular2 components and DOM aren't rendered and ready yet).

It only works if I wrap the call to `fw7App.addView(...)` into a timeout but this can't be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put that code in in parent's component method ngAfterViewChecked(). Read about the component lifecycle hooks here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview